# How do I get the number of character of a string element in a array? [C++]

Tags: c++, arrays

Example:

```
string array[3] = {"Hello", "HI", "Goodbye"};
cout << len(array[0]) << endl;      //print out the number 5
cout << len(array[1]) << endl;      //print out the number 2
cout << len(array[2]) << endl;      //print out the number 7
```

I understand that the len() function does not work in this example. How do I get the number of characters in each individual string elements in the array?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `strlen()` ?

Comment: @TodorSimeonov:  The array elements are `std::string`, so `strlen` won't work.

Comment: I have, but I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly because I got an error. I tried using the string library; that didn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: @TheRicky2061 Why on earth you are using a raw array of `std::string`? Is that a silly homework restriction? I'd recommend you rather should use a `std::vector<std::tring>` instead.

Comment: @TheRicky2061 Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the elements are `std::string`, you could use the `length` member:

```
cout << array[0].length() << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this earlier, but didn't work for some reason. Must have been a typo on my part. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Use the size() member functio (or the length() member function -- they're the same thing)

```
cout << array[0].size() << endl;
cout << array[1].size() << endl;
cout << array[2].size() << endl;
```